# Does a type that can be used in an Expression Tree in C# mean the same thing as being able to used in a Lambda Expression? Are they related?

Tags: lambda, expression-trees

I was reading this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/choosing-between-anonymous-and-tuple) and one of the remarks was,

> You might want to always use ValueTuple over Tuple, and anonymous types, but there are tradeoffs you should consider. The ValueTuple types are mutable, whereas Tuple are read-only. **Anonymous types can be used in expression trees, while tuples cannot.** The following table is an overview of some of the key differences. [emphasis mine]

It's not really a question on Tuples or Anonymous types per se, but the concepts.

Comment: Expression Tree uses the same types. C# Compiler just do not support translating Tuple constructor to Expression Tree, but you can do that dynamically always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression trees are represented in .NET as objects that point to other objects, that in turn point to other objects. For example, consider the following expression tree:

```cs
Expression expr = () => DateTime.Now.Hour > 18;
```

We can't actually write `new <X>` on most of the types in `System.Linq.Expressions`. But if we could write out the expression tree as a succession of object creations and initialization, it might look something like this:

```cs
new Expression<Func<bool>> {
    NodeType = ExpressionType.Lambda,
    Type = typeof(Func<bool>),
    Body = new BinaryExpression {
        NodeType = ExpressionType.GreaterThan,
        Type = typeof(bool),
        Left = new MemberExpression {
            Type = typeof(int),
            Expression = new MemberExpression {
                Type = typeof(DateTime),
                Member = typeof(DateTime).GetProperty("Now")
            },
            Member = typeof(DateTime).GetProperty("Hour")
        },
        Right = new ConstantExpression {
            Type = typeof(int),
            Value = 18
        }
    },
    ReturnType = typeof(bool)
}
```

There are two basic ways to create expression trees:

1. **Have the compiler do it.** Set a lambda expression syntax to a variable, property, or parameter of type `Expression<TDelegate>`. The C# compiler will automatically convert the code you write into a complete expression tree (as above).
2. **Call the factory methods on `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`.** Something like this:

   ```cs
   // using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

   Lambda(
       GreaterThan(
           MakeMemberAccess(
               MakeMemberAccess(null,
                   typeof(DateTime).GetProperty("Now")
               ),
               typeof(DateTime).GetProperty("Hour")
           ),
           Constant(18)
       )
   )
   ```

Because that part of the C# compiler which creates expression trees hasn't been updated in a long time, it doesn't handle many newer C# constructs (such as value tuples).

But you can always construct the expression tree using the factory methods, and using whatever .NET types you might want.

---

(NB. I've written a [library](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToString) that generates string representations of expression trees, such as the ones in this answer.)